# clojure next.jdbc database connection via configuration, without adding driver as dependency

Tags: jdbc, clojure, clojure-next.jdbc

I'm writing a sql tool in clojure that should be able to connect to any database.
Something like a light version of [HeidiSQl](https://www.heidisql.com/) or [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/).

I'm using [next.jdbc](https://github.com/seancorfield/next-jdbc).

Unfortunately the documentation states: *JDBC drivers are not provided by next.jdbc -- you need to specify the driver(s) you need as additional dependencies in your project.*

But I don't want my application to have a dependency to all supported databases. Say for instance I want to support Oracle, MS SQL and PostgreSQL. I can't demand the end-user to have to install all these 3 drivers if he just want to use my application to connect to PostgreSQL.

Comment: If you are creating a app / tool, would you not bundle all the drivers into the uberjar.  The app would then just load the required driver at runtime.  The end-user would not have have to install any of the drivers - they'd be there in the uberjar of the app you provide.  Perhaps I'm missing something in your question.

Comment: You
don't need to download _all_ drivers just to work with one DB.  JDBC
loads the driver on-demand basically when the first connection is
attempted.  You could also provide means to download the driver for the
user (download it into a classpath dir and restart the application, or
there are ways to do it [at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-to-load-jar-files-dynamically-at-runtime))

Comment: Just to be clear : This is a clojure application.  And the documentations states that I should add the drivers to the dependencies (in project.clj). So basically, like @dorab proposed, I should add all drivers as dependencies.  And include them in the uberjar too.